# WCF service secure so that only my METRO APP Client can call it

Tags: wcf, microsoft-metro, wcf-security

I have a WCF service hosted on AZURE. Also I have a metro app client that consumes that WCF service.
I want to make my WCF service secure so that only my METRO APP Client can consume that WCF service i.e. NO other Metro app or any application except my ABC (metro app name) METRO APP be able to consume the WCF service. I am a newbie to Metro app and WCF. It would be grateful if any one could share some help.